# How can I move the Core Data Stack from the AppDelegate into a new class?

Tags: ios, swift

I heard that the default code generated for the Core Data Stack in the AppDelegate is not supposed to be there actually. So I wanted to move it into a new class (named CoreData), but when it was in the AppDelegate I used this in the ViewController:

`let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext`

and then I could use that context variable for my create() func, delete() etc. all in the ViewController. Now I want to move that context as well to a ViewModel along with all those functions, but I am having issues on how to do that.
So I need to know how to declare that context var in my ViewModel since it's not in the AppDelegate anymore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you upgrade to a recent version of Xcode and create a new project that uses Core Data you will get an example of such a class.

Comment: In this kind of case, you create a class CoreData with a static var usually called shared that olds a shared of the CoreData type. Then you accès it via CoreData.shared.persistentContainer in your case.